# Why did the Kelvin look like a reboot starship

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot

Watching *Star Trek* 2009 and I came to the realization that the *USS Kelvin* (see below) looks very much like a 'reboot' starship (by 'reboot', I refer to the design of starships in the Abrams reboot series which differs from that of TOS).  Now I understand that the basis of this series is that it is that Nero's entrance resulted in the formation of an alternate timeline.  Logically, however, the events of the alternate timeline did not initiate until *after* this point though (ie approximately after the birth of James T Kirk).  Hence the events prior to Nero's emergence from the black hole occurred as they did in the (original) TOS timeline.

As the *Kelvin* was obviously commissioned and designed before this, however (i.e. it was designed and commissioned in the original TOS timeline), *why* would it look like a 'reboot' ship?  Surely it should have looked much more like a ship that would have come out of the uninterrupted timeline like the [Antares Class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Antares_type) or [Constellation Class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Constellation_class) (both of which seem to have been created before the Constellation according to [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation_starship_classes)).

**I am of course looking for an in-universe answer; the answer 'Abrams' will not suffice ;)**

NOTE: I am not asking why the *other* ships look different, as with an alternate timeline and the presence of Nero causing new events it is reasonable to assume the difference in design can be explained by different starship designs/designers (perhaps even slight derivations of technologies - consider the difference in the deflector dishes) being employed.  I am asking why ships *prior* to the alternate timeline being created looked like 'reboot' ships.

[image: The Kelvin]

Comment: Maybe just because it looks better than the old designs. Or in-universe, maybe there were starships with this design before Enterprise even in the old timeline, we juat never saw them in the series.

Comment: @KushtrimP. true; there do seem to be quite few Federation ships that we know of from before this time, although from simply looking at them this one seems quite different

Comment: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/inconsistencies-trekxi.htm#st09 follows the same line of thinking... although it has to be said, the site author is not overly fond of New Trek, basically saying that while they may be fun summer blockbusters to watch there is not really much ST spirit in them. Nevertheless the site is quite informative for all kinds of things.

Comment: In-universe, who says it looks any different? We aren't shown any Prime Universe ships to compare against. (If you're going to stay in-universe it's silly to assume that any given onscreen depiction is "accurate".)

Comment: @Leushenko [ENT 4x18](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly_(episode)) established that the TOS ship style was an in-universe thing, not a real-life limitation of special effects

Comment: @Izkata that's the Mirror Universe, which might not have been affected by the Narada split. After all, it was a different universe.

Comment: @Petersaber The episode took place in the Mirror Universe, but the ship they found in Tholian space during it had fallen through from the Prime universe in TOS 3x09, _The Tholian Web_.

Comment: @Izkata oh. In that case, I'm pretty sure this is purely a production thing, not an in-universe difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is an in-universe answer which appears on-screen. From your last paragraph -

> **I am not asking why the other ships look different**, as with an
>   alternate timeline and the presence of Nero causing new events it is
>   reasonable to assume the difference in design can be explained by
>   different starship designs/designers (perhaps even slight derivations
>   of technologies - consider the difference in the deflector dishes)
>   being employed. I am asking why ships **prior to the alternate timeline**
>   being created looked like 'reboot' ships.

To expand on your question, if I may, I would go on to wonder -- "Even if the reboot universe is a parallel universe which is fundamentally divergent from the original and thereby excused for being entirely separate, **why does Old Spock's ship (the *Jellyfish*) resemble the alt-universe ships?**"

There should not be any reason that the *Jellyfish's* design reflects any events in the alt-universe, because it is allegedly from a point some years after the last filmed events in the TNG franchise came to a close. The "questionably canon" *Star Trek: Countdown* comic establishes Geordi La Forge as the ship's designer. By rights, that ship *should* look like it was straight out of the old universe, but it neither externally nor internally acts or looks like anything from that universe.

I know you were not looking for such an answer, but sadly the films provide no real explanation. It's simply a new art direction. As proof, there are at least two vessels which follow this direction - the *Kelvin* and the *Jellyfish* - which both existed more-or-less independently of the events of the new Trek universe, yet inexplicably resemble that universe.

Comment: The Jellyfish is of a highly advanced design. I don't necessarily see that it resembles ships of the new timeline more than it resembles ships of the old timeline.

Comment: It sure as heck doesn't look like any TNG vessel, interior or exterior. Certainly not one designed by the engineer of the flagship of the Federation; not one LCARS DE? Goofy hangy-ceiling-chair that spins is somehow better than just, like, having a regular stuck on the ground chair? Weird moving parts on the outside in an age of engines with almost no moving parts on the exterior? Now if they'd made it look like a modded Runabout or something I might buy it, but this ship looks nothing like anything remotely Terran, Vulcan or otherwise from the prime universe.

Comment: Does it look like anything from the new timeline either?

Comment: Only everything

Comment: Do other ships from the new timeline have a "goofy hangy-ceiling-chair that spins", or "weird moving parts on the outside". If not, can you clarify what you mean by "everything"?

Comment: The interior/exterior design fits more with the new timeline than the old. It does not resemble any Vulcan or Federation ship from the late 24th century. I'm not an art major or an architect, I can't put it in relative nomenclature for you, it's indeed a subjective argument - but if one had to pair its design with TNG or reboot, I do not believe one can pair it to TNG influenced design in the slightest, except that it is a ship designed to operate in the vacuum of space and its computer talks.

Comment: So by "everything" you meant "a vague impression". Right. "*but if one had to pair its design with TNG or reboot*" -- but one doesn't. I've always assumed that its design is different from ships we've seen of the old and new timelines because it's strongly *Vulcan*.

Comment: Vulcan ships trend towards a particular set of designs though - either a three-pronged vessel like that in First Contact or the 'long sleek hull with circumscribed propulsion ring' shapes seen in ENT and very briefly in TNG (Redemption Pt 2). There's nothing vague about it, it doesn't follow the same artistic direction as was present during TNG franchises, and it fits in awfully easily when compared to the JJ-verse ships; the interior has that 'Apple Store w/ lens flare' motif like the bridge of the Enterprise. It is a new ship, sure, but it doesn't even harken to TNG-era tech.

Comment: The Kelvin was a product of a more aggressive stance by Starfleet, in response to the Xindi attack, which didn't happen in the original timeline.  Also, the events in the film "First Contact" may have influenced Cochrane's later input into starship design.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt Do you have any references that explicitly support that? The final episode of ENT says otherwise - Riker was in a holoprogram that included events from ENT.

Comment: @TJL  There may have been an Enterprise NX-01 that Riker used a holoprogram of, but it might not have been the same NX-01.  I do know that in a "Next Gen" episode Picard referenced sneak attacks specifying "Pearl Harbor and Station Salem One".  Failure to mention the Xindi attack which killed SIX MILLION people supports my assertion implicitly, but not explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

My theory is the timeline actually fractured from the original in Enterprise when the Xindi attack killed seven million people that hadn't died in the prime universe. The ripple effect from that would theoretically impact the people who were selected for design, research, and development teams at Star Fleet. Different team leaders would presumably make different design decisions leading to the design of the Kelvin being rejected by prime universe faculty but being approved by the Kelvin universe faculty. This also explains the size disparity between the prime Constitution and the Kelvin Constitution, after the Xindi attack the preference for larger and more combat oriented vessels lead to an Enterprise almost twice as large as it's prime universe counterpart. I'd bet the U.S.S Relatively is responsible for isolating both the Xindi and the Nero temporal incursions to the same timeline as is the common practice. I also have a theory that the Mirror universe is actually the original order of events that occurred without the Borg incursion. The violent reaction Lily Sloane and others had toward the Enterprise crew would have been directed toward the Vulcans and only wasn't because they had knowledge of the better future because of their contact with Picard and Co. In actuality the mirror universe is the prime universe and the prime universe was created paradoxically by the Borg of the prime universe deciding to stop First Contact, presumably to get their hands on the boronite ore used by Ketteract in the 23rd century to create an Omega molecule. This explains why the Borg that awoke in Antarctica in the 22nd century attempted to escape Earth rather than assimilate it, which would be the expected course of action, their mission was to acquire boronite from the only source they knew existed before the Federation used it in their failed experiment. Every timeline in Star Trek is the result of temporal manipulation, even the mirror universe got a Constitution class star ship from a future point in the prime universe that altered the natural course of events allowing Hoshi Sato to become Empress, it's no wonder there's a division of Star Fleet dedicated to preserving the time line in the 29th century.

Comment: That is _one_ big block of text. Can I suggest you [edit] it, split it into paragraphs etc? As well as including source material to back up your theory, so that it's not just a headcannon.

Comment: Unfortunately, pure speculation isn't what we are looking for. Please take a look at our [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/answering) to see what kind of answers are expected.